# Material ui emotion/styled how to combine multiple snippets of css classes?

Tags: javascript, material-ui, emotion

In the old way material ui (version 4 and earlier) styled components you could use className property to "Select" which styles are active, ie a component could be styled like:

```
const styles = (theme: ThemeTy) => ({
    root: {
        width: '100%',
    },
    rootLight: {
        color: theme.palette.getContrastText(theme.palette.primary.main),

    },
})
const useStyles = makeStyles(styles);

function MyComp() {
    const classes = useLocalStyles();
    return <Input
        className=classNames(classes.root, highContrast ? classes.rootLight : undefined)}
        value={100}
    />
}
```

However in the new api one would define the classes outside the component similar to styled-components does it:

```
const StyledInput = styled(Input)(({theme}) => `
    width: '100%',
`);
function MyComp() {
    return <StyledInput
        value={100}
    />
}
```

However how would I add the conditional styling? Would I have to use the `sx` element? And thus use conditional styling everywhere?

Answer (score 0):

You can pass any props to your `StyledInput` and then style the component based on them:

```
const StyledInput = styled(Input)(({ theme, showborders }) => ({
  width: "100%",
  border: showborders ? "3px solid red" : "none"
}));

...
const [showBorders, setShowBorders] = React.useState(false);
  return (
    <Box>
      <StyledInput showBorders={showborders ? 1 : 0} value={100} />
    </Box>
  );
```

[Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/inputs-demo-material-ui-forked-bsxzsd?file=/demo.js:325-563)

Comment: oh this is indeed a useful tip. Still a bit dubious how I would combine multiple "generic" css snippets that can repeat in multiple (type of) objects -- ie when I wish to show borders any element (input/div/button) would also have a modified padding and other stuff, but that's a different question... Just hoped an answer here would help there.

Comment: There are two problems with this solution before I could really use it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72929155/emotion-properties-to-style-object-with-react-gives-an-error

Comment: The first issue is solved by passing 1 or 0 for boolean values, I edited my answer.  The second issue would be easier to solve if there was provided a sandbox with the code.